# ClassyShark only showing method signatures

Tags: android, classyshark

When looking at some apk with classyshark I am only seeing method-signatures but no code like this:

```
public void onBackPressed() { ... }
protected void onCreate(Bundle) { ... }
protected void onDestroy() { ... }
```

As far as I understood classyshark should also show code. Is there anything ( setting, .. ) that I miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClassyShark only shows method signatures and general method counts. If you want to actually check the code you need other tools like [dex2jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/) (to convert dex files to .class files) and a Java decompiler such as [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/) to analyze the contents of the class files.